# Stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog the LinkedIn share button is not aligned correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

I just noticed that the share (social) buttons on https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog are misaligned. The LinkedIn button is centered at the bottom instead of the top.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

Inline code in the button:

```
element.style {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fix: `vertical-align: top;`

Environment:

- OS: Windows
- Browser: Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build)
  (64-bit)
- Browser 2: Chrome Version 77.0.3827.0 (Official Build) canary

Comment: You should apply this fix to the twitter button (`.hs-blog-social-share-item-twitter iframe`), since it's also (less noticeably) out of line.

Comment: This post made me smile. I salute my fellow perfectionists.

Comment: Potential workaround: Get rid of the linkedin button.

Comment: Thanks, now I can't sleep until this is fixed!

Comment: @LogicalBranch this doesn't seem like perfectionism. I'd expect perfectionism to be the misalignment of the Twitter button. The LinkedIn button is an in-the-face issue which should've been spotted and remedied without the need of a user report.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Brilliant Solution! I'm all in favour getting Linked-Out!

Comment: a good fix would be `.hs-blog-social-share .hs-blog-social-share-list .hs-blog-social-share-item {font-size:0}`. They all are iframe element so there will be no issue and this will avoid any miss vertical alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  As with all "easy" changes, I had to fight a bit with our CMS software to actually apply the css fixes, but those are now in place and the icons are appropriated aligned.

[image]

Thanks to @Termani Afif, who [suggested in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386117/stackoverflowbusiness-com-blog-the-linkedin-share-button-is-not-aligned-correctl#comment704210_386117) the clean solution I ended up using:

> a good fix would be `.hs-blog-social-share .hs-blog-social-share-list .hs-blog-social-share-item {font-size:0}`. They all are iframe element so there will be no issue and this will avoid any miss vertical alignment – Temani Afif